# What to save as Biometric Secret in ionic's FingerprintAIO API

Tags: ionic-framework, fingerprint, biometrics

I have an ionic-angular app that uses FingerprintAIO API for biometric authentication as follows:

```
constructor(private faio: FingerprintAIO) {}

// ...

// Saving a secret
this.faio.registerBiometricSecret({
    secret: "my-super-secret", // <--- What should I use as the biometric secret?
})
    .then((result: any) => console.log('biometric secret is saved', result))
    .catch((error: any) => console.log(error));

// Retrieving a secret          
this.faio.loadBiometricSecret()
    .then((secret: string) => console.log('biometric secret is loaded. Secret:', secret))
    .catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
```

My question: What should I save and retrieve as a biometric secret?

Comment: You found a solution?

Comment: Yes, will write a solution later today

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**
You should save a *long-live refresh-token* in the biometric registry.

**Detailed answer:**
Assuming your authentication system uses any type of access token (could be a JWT, but not necessarily), you can use the following scheme to issue a biometry token to be saved in the biometric registry:

**(A) Biometric signup**: This happens when registering a biometric token.

1. Log the user in, using regular username and password.
2. Send credentials to the server --> if authenticated, server issues a long-live refresh-token
3. Save refresh-token to the biometric registry using:

```
const biometryData: FingerprintSecretOptions = {
    secret: JSON.stringify(refreshToken)
};
this.faio.registerBiometricSecret(biometryData);
```

**(B) Biometric login:** This happens when a user wants to log-in using biometry.

1. Authenticate the user using biometry (fingerprint, faceId, etc.)
2. If authenticated --> Load refreshToken from the biometric registry and send it to the server
3. Server exchanges refreshToken for a valid access-token that the client can use to access resources of the app (similar to sending username and password to the server and getting a valid access-token).

**More details:**
For added security, you can implement The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749), which let's you create an access-token and a refresh-token to interact with an authentication and a resource server.

**Special implementations:**

Many companies and individuals choose not to implement the full RFC-6749 specifications, and go for something more lightweight that satisfies their needs. Since a refresh-token is a long-live token (more than just few hours), and since anyone with a refresh-token can generate access tokens, it is very important to keep it save and have ways to protect it. For example, some implementations of the OAuth Framework generate a new refresh-token every time it is used to issue a new access-token, while invalidating the previous one (so if it is stolen, it won't be useful). In my special case I found it useful to generate a refresh-token that uniquely identifies the **user and the device** together, by the device uuid, in a way that cannot be forged, while keeping the server stateless (i.e. without saving tokens to the the database), using the following scheme:

**(A) Biometric signup:** This happens when registering a biometric token.

1. Logs the user in, using regular username and password.
2. Send credentials to the server, along with `deviceUuid` --> if authenticated, server issues a long-live refresh-token that is a hashed `deviceUuid` and `userId`, for example:

```
const combinedToken = await this.hashUserIdWithDeviceUuid(deviceUuid, userId, salt);
return combinedToken;

async hashUserIdWithDeviceUuid(deviceUuid, userId, salt) {
    // Hash userId with the device uuid and the salt, and generate a unique hashed string
    const combinedString =  userId + '#' + deviceUuid;
    return await scrypt(combinedString, salt, 128).toString('hex'); //
}
```

3. Save refresh-token to the biometric registry as mentioned before.

**(B) Biometric login:** This happens when a user wants to log-in using biometry.

1. Authenticate the user using biometry (fingerprint, faceId, etc.)
2. If authenticated --> Load `refreshToken` from the biometric registry and send it to the server, along with `deviceUuid` and `userId`.
3. Server hashes `deviceUuid` and `userId` and compares them to the refreshToken:

```
const hasedUserIdAndDeviceUuid = await this.hashUserIdWithDeviceUuid(deviceUuid, userId, salt);
```

3. If successful (the hash and the refresh-token are equal), it means it is the same user using the same device --> Server sends back a valid access-token that the client can use to access resources of the app (similar to authenticating using username and password and getting a valid access-token):

```
if (hasedUserIdAndDeviceUuid !== refreshToken) {
    // not authenticated
} else {
    return this.generateANewJWT(); // Send back a valid JWT
}
```

Note: pay attention to the salt. In should be the same salt when registering and when signing-in. Follow best practices when dealing with saving the salt.